# Inside Django class-base CreateView, how to init intermediate model

Tags: django-views, foreign-key-relationship, django-class-based-views, manytomanyfield

I have three models, PiItem is the interface of Pi and Items models by "through".

Right now I want to create a new Items instance with new Pi instance and new PiItem instance inside Django CreatedView class.

Somehow I keep getting error message

*

> *****MultipleObjectsReturned at /product/ get() returned more than one PiItem*****

*

Any help will be highly appreciated 
THANKS

here are the models

```
class Pi(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(CompanyProfile, related_name='pi', null=True)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        #return u'%s, %s' %(self.company.companyprofile_name, self.reference_id)
        return u'%s' %(self.company.companyprofile_name)



class Items(models.Model):
    product_id = models.CharField("Product ID",max_length=50, blank=False, null=True, unique=True)
    in_pi = models.ManyToManyField(Pi, through='PiItem', blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.product_id


class PiItem(models.Model):
    item_name= models.ForeignKey(Items)
    pi = models.ForeignKey(Pi)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.pi.reference_id
```

and here is my view.py

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from pi.models import Items, PiItem, Pi
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class AddItemView(CreateView):

    context_object_name = 'Product_list'
    model = Items
    template_name = "product.html"
    fields = "__all__"

    def get_initial(self):
        in_pi = get_object_or_404(PiItem)
        return {
            'in_pi':in_pi
        }
```

and here is the template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block pi %}

<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    {{ form.get_form_class() }}
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>
```

Comment: my first intention is to create a new Items instance along with PiItem instance without any Pi object assigned ......after did a research on Google and several trying, it turns out that whenever the PiItem instance been created, there have to be Pi and Items instances connected with them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem most likely is here:

```
in_pi = get_object_or_404(PiItem)
```

You need to filter the PiItem object by passing additional arguments, such as foreigk key to each related model, like:

```
in_pi = get_object_or_404(PiItem, item_name=something1, pi=something2)
```